# how to read a custom object from com.typesafe.config

Tags: typesafe-config

Referring to `com.typesafe.config` library, I notice that while there are methods available to parse a value to `Integer`, `Boolean` etc., there aren't methods available to parse a value as a custom object. Am I correct?

https://lightbend.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/Config.html

I want to create a config file with the following values

```
cookieName: String = "id",
  cookiePath  = "/",
  cookieDomain = None,
  secureCookie  = true,
  httpOnlyCookie = true,
  useFingerprinting = true,
  cookieMaxAge  = None,
  authenticatorIdleTimeout = None,
  authenticatorExpiry: = 12 hours
```

and parse it into a case class

```
case class CookieAuthenticatorSettings(
  cookieName: String ,
  cookiePath: String ,
  cookieDomain: Option[String] ,
  secureCookie: Boolean ,
  httpOnlyCookie: Boolean, 
  useFingerprinting: Boolean ,
  cookieMaxAge: Option[FiniteDuration] ,
  authenticatorIdleTimeout: Option[FiniteDuration] ,
  authenticatorExpiry: FiniteDuration 
)
```

How could I do this? In the following snippet, I see that a method 'as' has been used but when I tried to use it in my code, the compiler couldn't find the 'as' method.

```
val config = configuration.underlying.as[JcaSignerSettings]("silhouette.oauth1TokenSecretProvider.signer")
```

The above code is from https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-seed/blob/master/app/modules/SilhouetteModule.scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to use something like [this](https://github.com/andr83/scalaconfig) which leverages the use of Scala `implicit`s. it has a default behavior that sort of figures out what Object what you need as long as the field names in the config matches the ones in your case class, but you can also provide your own reader to map the config fields to your case class.

i use this library with my own projects and i can say that it works as advertised.

Comment: thanks. Will check. Might take some time though so for the moment, I'll provisionally accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/kxbmap/configs

You can do things like

```
case class MyConfig(foo: String, bar: Int, baz: List[FiniteDuration])

val config = ConfigFactory.parseString("""
  my-config {
    foo = My config value
    bar = 123456
    baz = [1h, 2m, 3s]
  }
  """)

val result = config.get[MyConfig]("my-config")
```